# How to ID and remove elements when the CSS 'content property' hasn't loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project involving many radio buttons and each radio button is styled with a sprite. Like so:

```
input[type='radio']{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
  position:absolute;
  display:content;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:96px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:rebeccapurple;
  border-style:dashed;
}
.input[type='radio']:checked{
  filter:invert(100%);
}
```

Then, each radio button is tagged like this:

```
#i0000{content:url(0000.png);}
#i0001{content:url(0001.png);}
#i0002{content:url(0002.png);}
#i0003{content:url(0003.png);}
```

I am using the css stylesheet to provide different custom images for each radio button.
The problem is that if the content:url(image.png); does not load, this error appears:

```
GET file.../bad_image.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Normally I would be able to get around this by using an event listener either inline or in a script to iterate through them like so:

```
onerror=this.style.display='none';
```

But because I have used CSS to load the images, the event listener isn't working and the radio buttons still display.
How could I style these in such a way that when they do not load, the display is set to 'none'?

Comment: Could try getting those urls from getComputedStyle and pass them to new image elements and use your `onerror` to hide them

Answer (score 0):

If the styling of input elements is changed to:

```
input[type='radio']{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
  position:absolute;
  display:content;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 96px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rebeccapurple;
  border-style: dashed;
}
.input[type='radio']:checked{
  filter:invert(100%);
}
```

then the inputs for which the image has not loaded do not appear (though they are still there in the HTML).

This gets you part way to the solution without use of JS.

If it is essential to have the dotted border around images that have managed to load then you could loop through them all with JS, giving any that have offsetWidth > 0 a border-width of 1px. With admittedly a rather random/hacky pause of 2 seconds - will need adjusting, or perhaps even repeating if the load time is really long - here is some basic JS to put the dotted borders on:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
  for (let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].offsetWidth > 0) {inputs[i].style.borderWidth = '1px';}
  }
}, 2000);
```